# Объем товара, вывести. Ликвид

Tags: javascript, liquid

С помощью ликвида удалось дотянуться до объема товара (м3). (значения: 0,099 и 0,075, допустим.)
Они строковые.
Можно ли в js-е подтянуть эти значения, перевести их в цифры, навесить подсчет (в зависимости сколько было выбрано товаров по инпуту). Вывести в корзину.
Ниже код, ликвид:

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
  {% for prop in item.product.properties.properties %}
      {% if prop.handle  == 'size-m3-crt'%}
        {% for char in prop.characteristics %}
         <!-- size box ==  -->
         <div class="hidden-size capacity">{{ char.title }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

по JS-у, получение данных:

```
let capacity = $('.capacity').text();
```

Далее разбивал через split.
На этом полномочия всё :(

Answer (score 0):

```js
// let capacity = $('.capacity').text();

let capacity = '45 and 456.3';
let arr = capacity.split('and');

arr.forEach(e => { 

//parseFloat - число с плавающей точкой
//parseInt - целое число

console.log(parseFloat(e))
console.log(parseInt(e))
})
```

подробнее, по поводу навешивания подсчета, бы )